# qsort seems to change values

Tags: c, qsort

I'm stuck with following problem:

```
int sort_compare(const void *x, const void *y) {
    const int *xi = *(const int **) x;
    const int *yi = *(const int **) y;

    for (int i = 0; i < block_size; i++) {
        comp_x[i] = block[(*xi + i) % block_size];
        comp_y[i] = block[(*yi + i) % block_size];
    }

    return memcmp(comp_x, comp_y, block_size);
}

void sort() {
    for (int i = 0; i < block_size; i++) {
        printf("%d,", to_sort[i]);
    }
    puts("");
    qsort(to_sort, block_size, sizeof (int), sort_compare);
    for (int i = 0; i < block_size; i++) {
        printf("%d,", to_sort[i]);
    }
    puts("");
}

values:
    block_size = 5;
    block = "jkldj";
    comp_x, compy_y and to_sort are well allocated

output:
    0,1,2,3,4,
    3,0,1785357420,1,1684826986,
```

to_sort contains the first letter from a (circular) string e.g.

```
qwer
werq
erqw
rqwe
```

, represented as (0,1,2,3) needs to be sorted to

```
erqw
rqwe
qwer
werq
```

, represented as (2,3,0,1). I seem to get very large numbers, why is that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm surprised that that doesn't crash when you try to dereference `xi` and `yi`; are you on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine?

Comment: 'q' comes before 'r', so the result in your example should be `(2, 0, 3, 1)`.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Yes, that surprised me too. It crashed on my (64-bit) box as expected.

Comment: The two weird values in the array decode to "ldjj" and "jkld" when treated as little-endian 32-bit numbers. Those are both possible values for `comp_x` and `comp_y`, which arouses my suspicion that you are trashing memory somewhere. Since I don't see it in the code above, it might be in code you haven't posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x` and `y` passed into your comparator are pointers to your array elements.  Your array elements are `int`s, so to get the `int` values, you need to cast the `void` pointers into `int` pointers and dereference.  You have an extra layer of indirection in your code, it should really look like this:

```
int xi = *(const int *) x;
int yi = *(const int *) y;
```

Then just use `xi` and `yi` directly instead of `*xi` and `*yi` when doing the data comparison.

As an optimization, there's no need to copy the data into separate arrays and then `memcmp` them -- you can just compare them yourself in the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < block_size; i++) {
    char data_x = block[(xi + i) % block_size];
    char data_y = block[(yi + i) % block_size];
    if (data_x != data_y)
        return data_x - data_y;
}

return 0;
```

And as a further optimization, if you double the data in the `block` array (e.g. so that it has `"qwerqwer"` instead of just `"qwer"`), you can do the comparison in a single call to `memcmp`, since you no longer have to deal with the wraparound.  `memcmp` is heavily optimized, so if you have a lot of data, it can be much faster to use `memcmp` then a hand-written for loop.

Comment: +1, good optimization tip. I'm not sure it will solve OP's problem, though.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialise

```
const int *xi = *(const int **) x;
const int *yi = *(const int **) y;
```

the address of the element of `to_sort` is interpreted as a `const int**`, that is then dereferenced to give the values for `xi` and `yi`. That interprets the values in `to_sort` (and possibly beyond, if `int*`s are larger than `int`s) as pointers.

You should just cast the `void*`s:

```
const int *xi = (const int *) x;
const int *yi = (const int *) y;
```

Comment: What "both" have you tried? And in what way is it still not working?

Comment: I doubt the last part is the cause. Yes, it's UB, but since only `comp_x[i]` is actually being written to, it's unlikely that `to_sort` could be overwritten there.

Answer (score 1):

qsort() sings by giving it a a linear list of N-items, where any given item(n) address is computable using the based address + size of each 'item'. So start with something simple, and by simple I mean a list of pointers.

First, the circular-ness of the buffer can be emulated by simply splicing a copy onto the original (ideally less-one-char, but I'm not going to quibble about one byte). I.e.

```
"qwer" ==> "qwerqwer"
```

This can be done by:

```
char *buff = malloc(2 * blocksize);
memcpy(buff, to_sort, blocksize);
memcpy(buff+blocksize, to_sort, blocksize);
```

Now you have offsets 0..(blocksize-1), each of which being a blocksize of chars, that can be compared against one another without any special pointer math.

Next, build the list of pointers to actually sort, in this case,

```
char** ptrs = malloc(sizeof(char*) * blocksize); 
for (i=0;i<blocksize;i++)
    ptrs[i] = buff+i;
```

Next, a function that compares two "items". Our items, passed to us by address, are pointers to character strings. Again, the *addresses* past as left and right are memory locations were we will find two char *. The addresses themselves are *not* char *:

```
int block_compare(const void *left, const void *right)
{
    // memcmp would work for most platforms, but not all, so...
    return strncmp(*(char **)left, *(char **)right, blocksize);
}
```

Finally, send this to qsort() as such:

```
qsort(ptrs, blocksize, sizeof(char*), block_compare);
```

The final output will be a blocksize-length list of pointers into the fabricated circular buffer, each of which is referencing a blocksize sized chunk. The full text of everything described above follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t blocksize = 0;

int block_compare(const void *left, const void *right)
{
    // memcmp would work for most platforms, but not all, so...
    return strncmp(*(char **)left, *(char **)right, blocksize);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char to_sort[] = "qwer";
    size_t i = 0;

    // set blockize
    blocksize = strlen(to_sort);

    char *buff = malloc(2 * blocksize);
    memcpy(buff, to_sort, blocksize);
    memcpy(buff+blocksize, to_sort, blocksize);

    char ** ptrs = malloc(blocksize * sizeof(char*));
    for (i=0;i<blocksize;++i)
        ptrs[i] = buff+i;

    // now send the pointer list to qsort()
    qsort(ptrs, blocksize, sizeof(*ptrs), block_compare);

    // ptrs is sorted. do with it what you will.
    for (i=0;i<blocksize;i++)
    {
        fwrite(ptrs[i], sizeof(char), blocksize, stdout);
        fwrite("\n", sizeof(char), 1, stdout);
    }
    fflush(stdout);

    free(ptrs);
    free(buff);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Using "qwer" produces:

```
erqw
qwer
rqwe
werq
```

Another sample, using "asubstantiallylongerstringtest"

```
allylongerstringtestasubstanti
antiallylongerstringtestasubst
asubstantiallylongerstringtest
bstantiallylongerstringtestasu
erstringtestasubstantiallylong
estasubstantiallylongerstringt
gerstringtestasubstantiallylon
gtestasubstantiallylongerstrin
iallylongerstringtestasubstant
ingtestasubstantiallylongerstr
llylongerstringtestasubstantia
longerstringtestasubstantially
lylongerstringtestasubstantial
ngerstringtestasubstantiallylo
ngtestasubstantiallylongerstri
ntiallylongerstringtestasubsta
ongerstringtestasubstantiallyl
ringtestasubstantiallylongerst
rstringtestasubstantiallylonge
stantiallylongerstringtestasub
stasubstantiallylongerstringte
stringtestasubstantiallylonger
substantiallylongerstringtesta
tantiallylongerstringtestasubs
tasubstantiallylongerstringtes
testasubstantiallylongerstring
tiallylongerstringtestasubstan
tringtestasubstantiallylongers
ubstantiallylongerstringtestas
ylongerstringtestasubstantiall
```

Man I hope that was what you were looking for. (whew).

Comment: @Jens In C#-minor, I think =P